# PIC24F eeprom and XC16 MPLAB

Tags: mplab, eeprom, pic24

Can say me anyone why I get error when use this code in XC16 MPLAB? PIC24FJ64GA004

```
unsigned int __attribute__ ((space(eedata))) eeData[] = {100, 1, 22, 33, 44, 156, 3, 10, 1};
```

> error: space(eedata) not supported on this target

Sorry for beginner question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the PIC24FJ64GA004 doesn't have on-chip EEPROM for you to use.  The compiler recognizes this so throws that error.  Contrast this against, say, a PIC24F32KA302, which has 512 Bytes of on-chip EEPROM.

Your best bet if you need Non-Volatile memory to write to via your application is to:

A) Use a different target chip with dedicated on-chip EEPROM

B) Emulate an EEPROM using the unused flash program memory (There are [Libraries](http://www.microchip.com/SWLibraryWeb/product.aspx?product=Data%20EEPROM%20Emulation%20for%20PIC) out there for this)

C) Use an off-chip EEPROM that you can interface with via serial communication (such as [This](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/24AA64))